# Formatting Method ClusterResultsToString in a JTextArea + Visualize it

Tags: java, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, weka, jtextarea

[image: Screenshot of method ClusterResultsToString]

Hey guys, I wonder if there is a possibility to format the output of the Evaluation-method ClusterResultsToString. As you can see, the formatting via System.out.println is perfect, but if I put the output of ClusterResultsToString into a String and then into a JTextArea, the formatting becomes somehow garbage.

second questions: is it possible to visualize the output of ClusterResultsToString via PieCharts in an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Set the text are to a **fixed-width font** to repair the formatting.

To present the results differently,  use the Java API to access the desired values.